# Portable word alignment with C11 atomic operations

Tags: c, memory-alignment, c11, atomic

I would like to atomically swap a status word using the usual CAS pattern:

```
extern int status;

int change_state(void)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int old = atomic_load(&status);
        int new = prepare_new_status();
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&status, &old, new))
            return old;
    }
}
```

But since `old` might be not aligned, or might be a register variable, is `&old` portable?

If not, what is the correct way of atomically updating a status word on architectures where `int` access must be word-aligned?

Comment: `status` needs to be an `_Atomic` variable.

Comment: And why do you think that the address of `old` won't be properly aligned for an int pointer?

Comment: The only thing that is missing is the `_Atomic` qualification of `status`. Otherwise it looks as it is supposed to be. But you may shortcut a bit by moving the declarations and load outside the `while`.

Comment: Are you sure you need to name your variable `new` ?

Comment: @Michi: This is C, not C++, so `new` is perfectly cromulent variable name.

Comment: @NominalAnimal We cannot now what happens with this code.....tomorrow, isn't it?

Comment: @Michi: Well, I personally like to stick it now and then to people who believe C is a subset of C++.  This is one of those cases.  Since C++ proponents so often push C++ answers to C questions, why not give them pause every now and then? It is an opportunity to learn both ways, methinks.

Comment: @Jens: thanks, until now I didn't realize the first parameter must be `_Atomic`, gcc wasn't giving me any warnings with `-Wall -Wpedantic`. But if I move the load outside `while`, wouldn't this make a problem when another interrupt changes the `status`? Because `old` would then not be updated.

Comment: `atomic_compare_exchange_...` updates the `old` value if the comparison is false.

Comment: @JensGustedt: oh, right, that makes sense, that's why it accepts a pointer to the old value. I always forget this part.